# How to display console.warn message in lifecycle method(react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, web-component

I am deprecating one component(Toggletip) and I  need to display one warn message like  whoever uses that component should only get this warning message. How can I achieve this in lifecycle method.

solution with example will helpful.

Comment: use `componentDidMount` lifecycle method which runs your console warn message while your component gets mounted in the screen

Comment: You need to show us your code, what you did so far, and we will try to find a solution

Comment: can you share one example @SundaramoorthyAnandh

Comment: code is noting, like I used tooltip component inside Toggletip using trigger="click", so we dont want separate component, we achieve this by tooltip itself, so we want deprecate Toggletip component, we need send one warn message that whoever using this Toggletip component should get that message in console

Comment: is this what are you looking for?

const MyDeprecatedComponent = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`${MyDeprecatedComponent.name} => you are using a deprecated component!`);
  }, []);


  return (

  );
};